# Hide page number with <fo:page sequence>

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo, page-numbering

I want to hide the page number which appears at the page footer while using XSL-FO and the output format is PDF.

Is there a way to do this with `<fo:page sequence>`

Please let me know

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is usually done in `fo:page-sequence` regarding page numbering is just setting the initial page number or forcing a page count.

If you want to remove the page numbering from the footer, you need to look at where the footer is generated and remove the piece that is outputting the page numbering.

This is *usually* done with `<fo:page-number>` or `<fo:retrieve-marker>` in `<fo:static-content>` for a `<fo:region-after>` (in `<fo:simple-page-master>`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry if I confused by using the word "footer". Actually I meant the standard page number. I dont want to show any page numbers at all